# Разобрать объект в массив

Tags: массивы, объекты, javascript

Здравствуйте. Поставил перед собой цель написать свой [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) с передачей аргументов, контекста, обработчиками ошибок и прочим. Формат хочу сделать следующим:

```
cf(tasks, cb, limit);
```

tasks может быть объектом или массивом, аналогично с идейным вдохновителем. Значение каждого поля может быть следующим:

```
//Массив:
[[/*Задания, после которых можно выполнять текущее (пути могут быть относительные и абсолютные, но об этом потом)*/], fn, arg1, arg2, arg3, ErrorHandler1, ErrorHandler2],
//Объект:
{
    emitters: [/*Задания, после которых можно выполнять текущее (пути могут быть относительные и абсолютные, но об этом потом)*/],
    fn: Function /*Функция, которую будем выполнять*/
    args: Array /*Список аргументов*/
    context: Object,
    onError: Array /*Список "заданий", которые запустятся в случае ошибки*/
    ref: Boolean /*Будет ли callback дожидаться выполнения этого задания*/
}
//Ну или просто функция
```

Есть конструктор Task, какой принимает в себя значения поля и создает объект типа:

```
this.fn; // функция
this.args = []; // аргументы
this.context = null; // контекст по умолчанию
this.emitters = []; // задания, после которых запускать текущее (все instanceof Task)
this.listeners = []; // задания, которые запускать после текущего (все instanceof Task)
this.errorHandlers = []; //задания, которые запускать, если текущее выполнилось с ошибкой
this.ref = true; //будет ли callback дожидаться выполнения этого задания
```

Поиск заданий: если в emitters передается число num, то cf возьмет задание с индексом current + num. Если строка str, то с индексом str (для объектов использую Object.keys() и это работает).

Теперь, собственно, проблема. На данном этапе что-то не получается создать простой массив `parsedTasks`, все элементы которого являются instanceOf Task и, при этом, все элементы массивов emitters и listeners ссылаются на аналогичные элементы массива parsedTasks. Пробовал сделать сначала массив parsedTasks и потом расставлять эмиттеры и листенеры, но тут теряются имена task-ов и абсолютно на них сослаться не выходит (в случае передачи объкетов).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понял, зачем вообще нужен `parsedTasks`, наверное вам проще будет выложить код целиком и показать, где именно не работает комментом.

Там куча файлов и меня не интересует реализация. Мне нужен алгоритм, свежий взгляд на то, как создать этот массив. Дальше будет видно. Думаю сделать так, что б каждый отдельный Task знал, кто от него зависит и от кого зависит он. Так, думается, потом проще будет.

так непонятно где вы застряли. всякие зависимости обычно делаются так

```
 task.depends.push(othertask); //объявите Task.prototype.depends=[];
```

**Обновление**

непонятно, что вы имеете ввиду. Попробуйте представить, что вы не знаете ничего о вашей программе и вам приходит текст вопроса и комментарии которые вы даете. Очень трудно из обрывков понять.

Comment: @eicto Пока все это писал, что то и придумалось) Хотел спросить, как вы думаете, есть ли смысл добавлять "диапазоны" (ну, как бы, "выполнить задание после заданий от 1 до 5") или это уже лишние проблемы на мою голову?